# Oozie E0902: Exception occured

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm having an error, I can not solve.
When running the command:

```
  bin / oozie job -oozie http: // localhost: 11000 / oozie -config/usr/local/oozie-4.0.1/distro/target/oozie-4.0.1-distro/oozie-4.0.1/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
```

I get the following error:

```
  Error: E0902: E0902: Exception occured: [User: eduardo is not allowed to impersonate eduardo]
```

I searched the internet and stackoverflow, and found the solution. My hadoop version and 1.2.1, and the version of oozie and 4.0.1. below I will put my core-site.xml and job.properties.

core-site.xml:

```
<? xml version = "1.0"?>
<? xml-stylesheet type = "text / xsl" href = "configuration.xsl"?>

<! - Put site-specific property overrides in this file. ->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/data/tmp/hadoop/dfs</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
  <! - Oozie ->
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
     <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
     <value>oozie, eduardo</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

job.properties:

```
NameNode = hdfs://localhost:54310
jobtracker = localhost:54311
queueName = default
examplesRoot = examples

oozie.wf.application.path = ${namenode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir = map-reduce
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using spaces after commas in properties that have multiple values. Try changing your `hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups` property to:

```
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
     <value>oozie,eduardo</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did what you said, changed the core-site.xml and restart the hadoop and the oozie but, got the same error.